# Keeping object's state when user presses "Back" button

Tags: android, android-edittext, restore

I have an app in which I programmatically create an `EditText` view. I assign an ID to that view using `setId()`

```
myEditText.setId(100);
```

so that Android automatically saves that object's state when pausing/stopping the app (as I was advised to do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234653/edittext-not-automatically-saved-on-screen-orientation-change)). It **works** in these cases:

- (1) When I leave the app using the "Home" button: if I then come back to the app, the object's state (displayed text) is restored, as expected.
- (2) On a screen orientation change (which involves Android automatically destroying the activity and restoring it through a `Bundle`). The object state is also kept.

However, it **doesn't work** in this case:

- (3) When I leave the app using the "Back" button: if I then come back to the app, the `EditText` object is empty.

Any explanation as to why this happens? Does Android really distinguish between leaving the app with "Home" and with "Back"? According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html), the object's state should be automatically preserved, through a `Bundle`, *even when the activity is destroyed*. And that clearly happens in case (2). But not in case (3)!

If this is normal behaviour, how could I have the app's state automatically saved and restored when the user presses "Back"? I know I could use the SharedPreferences for that, but I'd rather have Android do that automatically, just as it does in cases (1) and (2).

This happens at least in Android 4.0 and 4.2 (I haven't tested others).

Comment: use Shared Preferences to the store the value and restore it. Once you click back button the current activity is popped from back stack and is destroyed. The previous activity in the stack takes focus

Comment: @Raghunandan Thanks, but as I said in the question, I'd like to do that without SharedPreferences. Ideally I'd like the same behaviour as with the Home button: Android saving and restoring automatically

Comment: the onDestroy() method is also called after the onPause() and onStop() method while you navigate away from the app using the back button. Please refer to the activity lifecycle for more information.

Comment: @LuisMendo here are the other storage options. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html. If you are looking for workarounds i don't know any.

Comment: @NirajAdhikari Thanks. According to [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html), the object's state should be restored automatically after `onDestroy()`... right?

Comment: @LuisMendo why not use singleton class for storing object??

Comment: @kalyanpvs I could do that. But if Android does it _automatically_ with the Home button, I think there has to be a way to achieve the same behaviour with the Back button. In fact, according to [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html), it should happen automatically for the Back button too.

Comment: @LuisMendo with using onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState you cant get the data because when the orienation changes Activity destroyed by os itself and Android will save your data and same will be passed to next re created Activity..So here you are destroying the Activity by pressing home button so you need to save the data and set it the newly created activity..When it comes home button press Activity object will not destroy..Activity state  only changed.

Comment: is your device low on memory? might be that is what is causing your data to be erased from memory as soon as the back button is pressed!

Comment: @kalyanpvs But when orientation changes the text _is_ restored automatically by Android for my app. So why not when Back is pressed?

Comment: thats because there Activity is destroyed by Android os itself so it will save data..but here with onBackPress Activity not destroyed by os so it won't save any data..

Comment: @LuisMendo we can talk about this in chat if you want. Just invite me.

Comment: @Emmanuel Thanks... I think I found the explanation: the doc explicitly says that the app state if cleared on Back press

Comment: @LuisMendo I also wanted to talk with you. I lived in Spain for a while, just wanted to connect.

Comment: Note: **onDestroy()** is not guaranteed to be called. If the system kills your app for lack of resources, it's only guaranteed to call **onPause()** (prior to 3.0) or **onPause()** and **onStop()** (3.0 and above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the explanation. I only needed to read the doc more carefully (thanks to @lentz for one of the links); see [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html):

> When your activity is destroyed because the user presses Back or the activity finishes itself, the system's concept of that Activity instance is gone forever because the behavior indicates the activity is no longer needed.
>
> If the user presses the Back button, the current activity is popped from the stack and destroyed. The previous activity in the stack is resumed. When an activity is destroyed, the system does not retain the activity's state.

The above explains behaviour (3) in my question.

> However, if the system destroys the activity due to system constraints (rather than normal app behavior), then although the actual Activity instance is gone, the system remembers that it existed such that if the user navigates back to it, the system creates a new instance of the activity using a set of saved data that describes the state of the activity when it was destroyed. The saved data that the system uses to restore the previous state is called the "instance state" and is a collection of key-value pairs stored in a Bundle object.

The above probably explains behaviour (1) and (2).

What I don't see is *why* the user pressing Back should be interpreted as "the activity is no longer needed" ("its state needs not be preserved"). But that's a different matter.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I had the EXACT same problem. Now I understand it but I still don't know how to fix that. Neither did you mention it. Any ideas @LuisMendo?

Comment: @Sudhanshu Well, as I see it now, there is nothing to _fix_. Android forgets about the activity state when user presses Back, but not when they press Home. That seems to be how Android works: Home and Back work differently. If you want to preserve state on Back press, you should do it manually with SharedPreferences as stated in the comments above

Comment: thanks for the reply! I guess I don't have a choice :(

Answer (score 3):

You really should study activity life cycles as there are many many ways to solve the problem. Since your activity is typically pulled off of the stack and destroyed when you navigate back one quick but not necessarily the best way is to make sure your activity flagged as singleTop or singleInstance in the manifest that way it is not pulled off of the stack and recreated when you navigate back and forth. You could also use the singleton Application class. Or pass the text back and forth as params. Or use a database. Or use MVC or some other programming paradigm that will allow your views to be destroyed and recreated with out the data populating them going with it. Lots of "or's". Study activity life cycles and then look at how you have your application architecture setup already and choose the method that will work best for you.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: +1 Thanks. However, my question was much narrower: why the view state is _automatically_ retained on Home press but not on Back press. Reading more carefully into the doc, it says exactly that: Home and Back are really treated differently. So it's "normal" behaviour, if by "normal" we understand "specified by the documentation"