# TextView content lost after rotation

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a similar problem like in this question: [EditText not automatically saved on screen orientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19234653/1639556)

High level view: I create UI from XML but recreate one or two TextViews programatically (only way to set a style from code). When I rotate the screen debugger shows that its text comes from activity XML not what user entered before rotation.

Code view:

activity_calc.xml:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/operandFirst"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="50"
        style="@style/FormulaValue" />
```

Activity.java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calc);
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onCreate()" + ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.operandFirst)).getText());
    if (formula == null && savedInstanceState == null) {
        prepareNewFormula();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelable("formula", formula);
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onSaveInstanceState()" + ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.operandFirst)).getText());
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
    formula = state.getParcelable("formula");
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onRestoreInstanceState()" + ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.operandFirst)).getText());
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // HERE - getText() will return "50" which is default value in activity XML
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onResume()" + ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.operandFirst)).getText());

    unknown =((TextView)findViewById(R.id.operandFirst));

    // COMMENTED OUT AFTER UPDATE: unknown = replaceView(view, R.layout.template_unknown_value, parent);

    unknown.setText("");
}

// create TextView again at the same position with the same id
private TextView replaceView(TextView view, int template, LinearLayout parent) {
    parent.removeView(view);
    TextView textView = (TextView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(template, null);
    textView.setId(view.getId());
    int index = getWidgetPosition(view.getId());
    parent.addView(textView, index, view.getLayoutParams());
    return textView;
}

public void digitClicked(View view) {
    CharSequence digit = ((TextView)view).getText();
    unknown.append(digit);
}
```

The method `replaceView` will take id of XML with styled TextView:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:singleLine="true"
    style="@style/FormulaUnknownValue" />
```

I wonder why the text is not preserved and why there is the very first original text that was replaced during startup.

--- UPDATE ---

I commented out TextView recreation. Though I still receive "50" from `activity_calc.xml` in `onResume` instead of value entered before rotation.

```
03-14 20:31:06.219 D/CalcActivity﹕ onCreate() 50
03-14 20:31:06.225 D/CalcActivity﹕ onResume() 50
03-14 20:31:54.138 D/CalcActivity﹕ onSaveInstanceState() 5
03-14 20:31:54.272 D/CalcActivity﹕ onCreate() 50
03-14 20:31:54.279 D/CalcActivity﹕ onRestoreInstanceState() 50
03-14 20:31:54.280 D/CalcActivity﹕ onResume() 50
```

Comment: Do you call super.onRestoreInsranceState()? It is missing from your code.

Comment: Good point. Nevertheless adding super call did not help. In fact I accidentally clicked home button and when I returned back, the formula was changed as well.

Comment: Maybe you could save the text during onPause()

Comment: I could. But I prefer to understand this behavior instead of providing workarounds. TextViews shall be saved by Android automatically.

Comment: Only views with unique IDs preserve their content. In your case you have to set the text manually after you restore formula.

Comment: Good point. What are 'unknown', 'view' and 'parent' in onResume()? Where do you initialize them? Some code is missing, maybe it will help.

Comment: I commented out TextView replacement so the TextView has unique id and it is always unique. I will update the question with portion of activity_calc.xml

Comment: On your `onResume()` you can put ` unknown.setText(formula);`?  It looks like you're logging the default number and not setting it.

Comment: I want to keep the value entered by the user. I assumed that it will be restored after onRestoreInstanceState.

Comment: Right, but your logs are getting the default text from the textview id.  Maybe remove the default from your xml or re-`setText()` during your `onResume()`

Comment: I removed the default value and now the view is empty. The problem is not default value but why android (I run Nexus 4 with Android 5) does not keep the value. I could save it manually as @meirshapiro recommended, but as I read it is Android responsability. But it does not work. Why? Do I do something wrong? Or I misunderstood a documentation and I have to preserve the state of all components myself?

Comment: Android removes any dynamic value that isn't saved.  When you do your `onResume`, can you `Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onResume()" + formula);`