# Android - save textedit text after orientation changed - edittext not found

Tags: java, android, textedit

I am getting NullPointerException for `editText.setText(buttonText);` line, so it looks like my `editText` is being destroyed after orientation is changed. I know the activity lifecycle, but I am unsure where to put declaration of `editText`.

The buttonText seem to be populated correctly though.

My class:

```
package com.example.orientation;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.EditText;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    EditText editText;
    String buttonText = "";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.d("StateInfo", "onCreate");

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtField1);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            editText.setText(buttonText);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString("buttonId", editText.getText().toString());

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    };

    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        buttonText = savedInstanceState.getString("buttonId");
        //editText.setText(buttonText);
    };

}
```

XML:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtField1"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

**EDIT:** Sorted! I had another layout for landscape view and on that XML I didn't have EditText element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EditText not automatically saved on screen orientation change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234653/edittext-not-automatically-saved-on-screen-orientation-change)

Comment: Nope, the link above describes the idea of: `buttonText` from my code, in my example it's the `editText` which is null.

Comment: Remove  **editText.setText(buttonText);** from **onRestoreInstanceState**

Comment: Still the same, the exception is throwing at line: 40 which is the setText() in onCreate() method.

Comment: check  **buttonText!= null** instead of **savedInstanceState != null**

Comment: buttonText is set correct, it's the editText which is null

Comment: Is error only occur when you rotate the screen?

Comment: That is correct, only when I change an orientation.

Comment: Do you have different layout xml files for portrait and landscape modes?

Comment: Ah yes I did, and button wasn't on that second layout. It's sorted now, thanks!