# How to save EditText text on orientation change?

Tags: android, android-edittext, onsaveinstancestate

Although the concept is very simple, I seem to be having difficulty saving the text value of a TextEdit when the orientation of the device changes. When I change the orientation, the text inside my EditText is erased.

The view hierarchy is as follows:

```
Activity
    View Pager
        Fragment
            Recycler View
                View Holder
                    Edit Text
```

- I tried setting `freezesText` to `true` in the xml layout for the `EditText` to no avail.
- In the fragment, I tried saving the text in `onSaveInstanceState()` and restoring in `onActivityCreated()`, but it seemed like `onSaveInstanceState()` was never getting called.
- In the activity, I tried saving the text in `onSaveInstanceState()` and restoring in `onCreate()`, but the `EditText` was null at that point.
- I tried setting `saveEnabled` to true in the xml layout for the `EditText` which also didn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you set the ID to your EditText on xml? It's most important things that is necessary for saving texts in EditText? Also your question is duplicate this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19234974/2557258

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214600/save-data-and-change-orientation

Comment: Yes, the EditText has an ID set

Comment: @JosueEspinosa It looks like you doing something wrong. Maybe you setting new adapter to recycler each time onCreate? It would be easier to help you if you show your full fragment code.

Comment: @Yazon2006 The view hierarchy is pretty complex, I'll add more relevant code shortly

Comment: @Yazon2006 Yes, I think that might actually be the underlying issue. In my fragment, in `onActivityCreated()`, I create the `RecyclerView` and set the adapter. Should that not be the case?

Comment: @JosueEspinosa if you created new instance of adapter - thats the point. Try to create it only in case if it is null to avoid unnecessary recreation of adapter. Still can't say for sure...

Comment: Hmm, wrapping the setup in `if (mAdapter == null)` still doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: share code for this.

Comment: you have to use
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
It will give you back the bundle that you saved in the  
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

Answer (score 2):

Try declaring `saveEnabled = "true"` in your editText inside xml layout

Answer (score 0):

put this in your Fragment `onCreate()`

```
setRetainInstance(boolean)
```

Read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) with full example code