# EditText saved the value after device rotation automatically

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, orientation

I created a sample application in Android Studio to learn about the life cycle of an Android application. I know that orientation change completely restarts the activity (i.e. OnCreate method is called again).
As far as I know, orientation change should have destroyed the context and shown a blank text after device rotation. But somehow without overriding onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState methods it is saving the context.

I don't have any fragments. It just the basic template that is provided by Android studio, with few overridden life cycle methods.
Here is my MainActivity class:

```
package com.example.android.a2_screen_orientation_change;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.i(TAG, "in method onStart");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i(TAG, "in method onResume");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Log.i(TAG, "in method onRestart");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.i(TAG, "in method onPause");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.i(TAG, "in method onStop");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(TAG, "in method onDestroy");
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.a2_screen_orientation_change.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

AbdroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.a2_screen_orientation_change">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Image:
[image: Text got saved even after device orientation change]

Comment: What about this activity is leading you to think that the state isn't going back to square one?  Kindly list such state in your question.

Comment: wait, I will add a screenshot

Comment: `EditText`s automatically save/restore the text in the saved state bundle. You don't need to do anything for it to happen. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setFreezesText(boolean) (Note that "icicle" is the old term for the saved state bundle.)

Comment: Minor correction: `EditText`s _with unique IDs_ will save their text automatically.

Comment: @MikeM. Why just EditText, is this behaviour common to other Views?

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat I can't say why the designers decided to have `EditText` behave like that, but I would guess that it's just because it makes the developer's job a little easier, not having to track each externally modified text. Other `View`s can save and restore state, if they're configured as such. Anything that contains an `EditText` with an ID will save its text; e.g., `SearchView`. Also, `ListView` will save its scroll position, `ViewPager` will save it's current item index, `DrawerLayout` will save its drawer state (for only one drawer, though), etc.

Comment: @MikeM. Given this is the behaviour what are the cases where I should be using  onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState?
With an example if possible.

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat You'd use those for anything that you need similarly saved/restored that's not tracked inherently by the `View`s or framework. There's really no complete list, or anything, and there can't be, frankly. I guess it's just something that you get to know as you become more familiar with everything. The first thing that comes to mind, though it's not `View`-related, is when you might dynamically create a `Uri` to pass on an `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent`, and you'd need to save that in case your `Activity` is temporarily destroyed when the camera app opens.

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat I'm not really sure what you're asking, there. Also, all of this would be more appropriate as a whole new question, rather than a discussion in comments on an old post. We're really not supposed to have prolonged conversations here. Please feel free to post a new question with your concerns. Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the EditText is a focused view, so in `PhoneWindow`, it's state will be saved automatically in `saveHierarchyState()` method. You can see the code:

```
@Override
public Bundle saveHierarchyState() {
    Bundle outState = new Bundle();
    if (mContentParent == null) {
        return outState;
    }
    SparseArray<Parcelable> states = new SparseArray<Parcelable>();
    mContentParent.saveHierarchyState(states);
    outState.putSparseParcelableArray(VIEWS_TAG, states);
    // save the focused view id
    View focusedView = mContentParent.findFocus();
    if (focusedView != null) {
        if (focusedView.getId() != View.NO_ID) {
            outState.putInt(FOCUSED_ID_TAG, focusedView.getId());
        } else {
            if (false) {
                Log.d(TAG, "couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view "
                        + focusedView + " has no id.");
            }
        }
    }
    // save the panels
    SparseArray<Parcelable> panelStates = new SparseArray<Parcelable>();
    savePanelState(panelStates);
    if (panelStates.size() > 0) {
        outState.putSparseParcelableArray(PANELS_TAG, panelStates);
    }
    if (mActionBar != null) {
        outState.putBoolean(ACTION_BAR_TAG, mActionBar.isOverflowMenuShowing());
    }
    return outState;
}
```

and the code in `TextView`:

```
@Override
public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
    // Save state if we are forced to
    final boolean freezesText = getFreezesText();
    boolean hasSelection = false;
    int start = -1;
    int end = -1;
    if (mText != null) {
        start = getSelectionStart();
        end = getSelectionEnd();
        if (start >= 0 || end >= 0) {
            // Or save state if there is a selection
            hasSelection = true;
        }
    }
    if (freezesText || hasSelection) {
        SavedState ss = new SavedState(superState);
        if (freezesText) {
            if (mText instanceof Spanned) {
                final Spannable sp = new SpannableStringBuilder(mText);
                if (mEditor != null) {
                    removeMisspelledSpans(sp);
                    sp.removeSpan(mEditor.mSuggestionRangeSpan);
                }
                ss.text = sp;
            } else {
                ss.text = mText.toString();
            }
        }
        if (hasSelection) {
            // XXX Should also save the current scroll position!
            ss.selStart = start;
            ss.selEnd = end;
        }
        if (isFocused() && start >= 0 && end >= 0) {
            ss.frozenWithFocus = true;
        }
        ss.error = getError();
        if (mEditor != null) {
            ss.editorState = mEditor.saveInstanceState();
        }
        return ss;
    }
    return superState;
}
```

So, if you remove the id of the EditTextView in your xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.a2_screen_orientation_change.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You will see what you want! (Tanks for supplement from @Mike M.)

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it worked.
Interesting behaviour !

Comment: It's true that removing the ID will cause the `EditText` to not save its text, but the `saveHierarchyState()` method you've referenced doesn't have anything to do with that. All that method is doing - as far as an `EditText` is concerned - is saving its ID, so the same one will be given focus when the hierarchy is restored. It does nothing with the text.

Comment: No problem. Here are links to the code that's actually doing it, if you wanna include that in your answer instead: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#4122, https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/EditText.java#68. And here's the relevant info from the docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setFreezesText(boolean). Of course, `onSaveInstanceState()` just won't be called if it doesn't have an ID. Cheers!

Comment: @vesper What is the meaning of a focused view?

Comment: @MikeM With your comment I'm doubtful whether this should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Android is by default, restoring the state of some Views.
In your Layout xml, add `android:saveEnabled="false"` to your EditText. And the value of EditText will not be retained.

Comment: I saw a few tutorials in which text was lost after the orientation change.
Is this default behaviour added in newer versions of Android ?

Comment: According to Android Reference, this behavior doesn't seem to have changed from default. But if you want to refresh (clear) the data of the View, you must set this attribute to false. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#saveEnabled

Comment: @LakshmikantDeshpande If you don't specify the id for the edit text the value won't be retained.

Answer (score 1):

Android automatically handles saving the state & restoring until you explicitly specify the

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

in your mainifest

In case, you do not have an `id` for the ui element, Android will not be able to restore the state of the element.

Please refer to the answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19234974/1099156

Comment: I specified android:configChanges="orientation" in the manifest, and still on rotation the edit text retains the values. snipped from my manifest is <activity android:name=".A"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            >