# How can we save editText on screen orientation without assigning id to editText in layout file

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Android beginner experiments:

I have created a layout with only an `editText` without an id.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter Text"/>
```

Now , how should I prepare my Java code so that on orientation, the text in editText remain saved ?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234653/edittext-not-automatically-saved-on-screen-orientation-change

Comment: What is the reason to let user to enter something which your app has a hard time retrieving later?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov, I'm experimenting the project.

Comment: @sasikumar I'm not getting the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Goto your android manifest, find the activity you are using and be sure it is like this:

```
<activity
            android:name=".YourActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden" />
```