# how to keep text of dynamic added edittext on configuration change in android

Tags: android

I have to add some dynamic view based on server response and some of them are Edittext

```
     viewmodel.needs.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        it.data?.let {
        
            val set = ConstraintSet()
            //adding first edittext price and label
                if(it.price.price1Requierd==1) {

                    val lbl_price1=AppCompatTextView(requireContext())
                    lbl_price1.id=View.generateViewId()
                    lbl_price1.setText(it.price.price1Title)
                    lbl_price1.setTypeface(typeface)
                    cl_price.addView(lbl_price1,ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))
                    set.clone(cl_price)
                    set.connect(lbl_price1.id,ConstraintSet.TOP,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.TOP)
                    set.connect(lbl_price1.id,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.RIGHT)
                    set.applyTo(cl_price)
                    et_price1 = AppCompatEditText(requireContext());
                    et_price1.id=View.generateViewId()
                    et_price1.setHint(it.price.price1Title)
                    et_price1.inputType=InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER + InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED
                    et_price1.setTypeface(typeface)
                    et_price1.maxLines=1
                    et_price1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_select)

                    cl_price.addView(et_price1,ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))

                    set.clone(cl_price)
                    set.connect(et_price1.id,ConstraintSet.TOP,lbl_price1.id,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)
                    set.applyTo(cl_price)



                }
            //adding second edittext price and label
                if (it.price.price2Requierd==1) {
                val lbl_price2=AppCompatTextView(requireContext())
                lbl_price2.id=View.generateViewId()
                lbl_price2.setText(it.price.price2Title)
                lbl_price2.setTypeface(typeface)
                cl_price.addView(lbl_price2,ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))
                set.clone(cl_price)
                set.connect(lbl_price2.id,ConstraintSet.TOP,et_price1.id,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,top_margin)
                set.connect(lbl_price2.id,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.RIGHT)
                set.applyTo(cl_price)

                et_price2 = AppCompatEditText(requireContext());
                et_price2.id=View.generateViewId()
                et_price2.setHint(it.price.price2Title)
                et_price2.inputType=InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER + InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED
                et_price2.setTypeface(typeface)
                et_price2.maxLines=1
                et_price2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_select)
                cl_price.addView(et_price2,ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))
                set.clone(cl_price)
                set.connect(et_price2.id,ConstraintSet.TOP,lbl_price2.id,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)

                set.applyTo(cl_price)

            }





        }?: run {
            it.message.shortToast(requireContext())
        }
    })
```

the Edittext are Added correctly as i want but the problem is when fragment is recreated for example on orientation change or if another fragment is replaced the text of edittexts are lossing actuly the views are recreating . so how can i keep the state of edittext or any other dynamic added view like checkbox or .. tanx for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try set an unique id for the dynamically created TextView.

```
textView.setId(View.generateViewId());
```

Link:

[EditText not automatically saved on screen orientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234653/edittext-not-automatically-saved-on-screen-orientation-change)

Comment: but i am already adding uniqe ids to edittexts 
 et_price1.id=View.generateViewId()